# Passing existing prop to component and appending

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const LNTextField = props => {
  const classes = useStylesReddit();
  return (
    <TextField
      variant="filled"
      InputProps={{ classes, disableUnderline: true }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

This is a functional component
Let's say I would like to add something to the InputProps object when using this component, while maintaining the InputProps object inside the functionalComponent
How can I do that?
for example;

```
<LNTextField
                InputProps={{
                  endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment
                      className={styles.optionalAppendedText}
                      position="end"
                    >
                      Optional
                    </InputAdornment>
                  )
                }}/>
```

Right now its overwriting the InputProps in the component

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about use different props name for `InputProps` from the parent? Let say, InputProps from parent is named with `InputPropsParent`. And, you can try to do this:

```
const LNTextField = props => {
  const classes = useStylesReddit();
  return (
    <TextField
      variant="filled"
      InputProps={{ ...props.InputPropsParent, classes, disableUnderline: true }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

**updated**

As the OP comment, the above code is not working. Below code is the working code, though idk if this is the best approach or not.

```
const LNTextField = props => {
      const classes = useStylesReddit();
      return (
        <TextField
          variant="filled"
          InputProps={{ ...props.inputpropsparent, classes, disableUnderline: true }}
          {...props}
        />
      );
    };
```

Comment: index.js:1375 Warning: React does not recognize the `InputPropsParent` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `inputpropsparent` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Comment: It worked as lowercase tho, is this the best approach tho? there's no way to just append InputProps without using a different prop name?

Comment: How about using camelCased? Does it work? I preferred to use camelCased if it worked. Idk, have you try to use same props name? and replace the `...props.InputPropsParent` with `...props.InputProps`?

Comment: sorry but I don't know another approach for your issue